# php round number include zero if .50

Tags: php

I want to round a number for e.g 269.00 and I round it like

```
round($price, 2)
```

which outputs 269 but when I have a value like 269.50 it ouputs 269.5 and I want to have the zero at the end this is for pricing products

Answer (score 17):

Use [`number_format`](http://www.php.net/number_format) afterwards:

```
$price = number_format(round($price, 2), 2);
```

This also adds commas as thousands separators.

Comment: but then includes .00 for all other items that are lets say 12.00

Comment: @KDM: Yes; it would be inconsistent otherwise. If you want it to omit the decimals if it is an integer, explicitly test for that.

Comment: How do I test for that then the fields are 2 two decimal places

Comment: @KDM: Probably something like `if(abs($price - round($price)) < 0.005)`, but I may not have fully thought that through.

Comment: May be you can check by explod by . and then count string length however there may be function for that

Comment: There is no point in using round in your example, number_format rounds too. $price = number_format($price,2);

Comment: using number format turns it to a string? how can i keep it a decimal type

Comment: @bonez: A floating-point type is *going* to chop off any trailing zeros, and there’s no way around that. If you need those trailing zeros, it’s going to have to be a string. If, on the other hand, you don’t need those trailing zeros, then just don’t use `number_format`; stick to `round` and leave it there.